# How to change display of Featured Products element in WooCommerce Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, wordpress-featured-image

I am using Featured Products element of WooCommerce in my woocommerce wordpress website.

The issue is that there are 5 featured products. 4 of them are displaying on first row and the 5th one is showing on the next row, alone. I want to center the last product. How do I do that?

Comment: share your feature product code

Comment: Actually, this is the problem. I have no idea where the element is or how to locate it. I can't find it in widgets or plugins.

Comment: This layout is made by wooCommerce default. four column layout which is starts with left align products. if you have 5 product then I suggest you to write in page css. find the 5th product id and align it into center.